# limsup of a functon and sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I would like to know if this statement is true: if $\limsup_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x)=\lambda$ then exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ that converges to $x_0$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } f(x_n)= \lambda$. Intuitively i think this is true, but i would like to understand why it is true or false.

Comment: Start by giving us the definition of  $\limsup$ that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true.

Let $E$ be the domain of $f$. By definition, $\limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\lambda$ means that$$\lim_{\delta\to0}\bigl(\sup\{f(x)\,|\,x\in E\cap(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\}\bigr)=\lambda.$$Take $\varepsilon>0$. Then, by the previous equality,$$\sup\left\{f(x)\,\middle|\,x\in E\cap\left(x_0-\frac1n,x_0+\frac1n\right)\right\}\in[\lambda,\lambda+\varepsilon)$$for some $n\in\mathbb N$. So, there is some $x_n\in\left(x_0-\frac1n,x_0+\frac1n\right)$ such that $x_n\in[\lambda,\lambda+\varepsilon)$ and this implies that $\bigl|\lambda-f(x_n)\bigr|<\varepsilon$. Since $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):|x_0-x_n|<\frac1n$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$.

Comment: Thank you. What if I use the definition $ \limsup f(x):= inf\{sup\{f(x) \mid x \in (E \cap U \backslash \{x_0\})\}\} $ where $U= (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ and $\delta$ is variable?

Comment: In your definition, the value of $f(x_0)$ does not matter. Other than that the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: I have another question: if $f$ has an upper bound in an interval does it mean that $f$ has a $ \limsup $ for some $x_0$ in that interval?

Comment: @emilio If $f$ has an upper bound in an interval, then $\limsup_{x\to x_0}f$ exists for *every* $x_0$ in that interval.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand why do you use $\frac{1}{n}$ and not another number. And  it seems to me that the proof is valid for all $\{x_n\}$, can you explain me why it is not so ?

Comment: @emilio I use $\frac1n$ so that $x_n\in\left(x_0-\frac1n,x_0+\frac1n\right)$, that is, so that $|x_0-x_n|<\frac1n$. Remember that I want to have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$. I could have used, say $\frac1{n^2}$ and the proof would also work. I have no idea about what you meant when you say that the proof is valid for all $\{x_n\}$.